# 3D processing.js with webcam

Tags: javascript, canvas, webcam, processing.js

As soon as I try to do a rotate on the stage/canvas after generating an image from a webcam in processing.js i get an "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function".
without the rotate the code works fine. and works fine in "normal" processing.
any ideas? i'm not transforming the webcam image but a copy of it. but seems that where it fails, and only after the rotate is added after it - on a copy of the webcam image. any ideas? been butting my head against this for a few weeks...

```
void setup() {
    size(800, 600,P3D);
    ctx = externals.context;
}

void draw() {
    pushMatrix();
    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height); // <--fails here. 
    img=get();
    pushMatrix();
    translate(width/2, height/2);
    rotateX(radians(20));
    // do something
}

// video is defined outside processing code in js:

function successCallback(stream) {
    // Set the source of the video element with the stream from the camera
    if (video.mozCaptureStream) {
     video.mozSrcObject = stream;
    } else {
     video.src = (window.URL && window.URL.createObjectURL(stream)) || stream;
    }
    video.play();
 }
```

Comment: Can you post a minimal working example that replicates this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should convert video stream to PImage.

see below.

- http://jsdo.it/kjunichi/9gXZ/js
- http://jsrun.it/kjunichi/9gXZ

good luck!